# is it necessay to get a reference letter from the place i work to re enter japan while i am on working visa?

Tags: visas, japan

is it necessary to get a reference letter from the place I work to re enter japan while i am on working visa? cause Iam going to my home Country.

Comment: You are in Japan on a working visa and you’re asking about going out of the country (‘home’) for a short period?

Comment: I've answered your question, though it might be better to ask such questions on the [Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japan).

Comment: @John The answer I had in mind but I was waiting for OP’s clarification that that was actually their situation ;) For the record, the question is absolutely fine here because it is about travelling but it might be borderline off-topic at Expats because it’s not about the everyday life there.

Comment: @Jan True. Maybe you're right! :-)

Answer (score 4):

As of [July 2012](http://www.immi-moj.go.jp/newimmiact_1/en/point_3-4.html), if you wish to leave Japan for a under a year, you can pick up a "Special Re-entry Permit" at the airport just before the immigration desks:

[image]

Simply fill in the departure part, and present it with your passport and residence card at the immigration desk. The immigration officer will staple the "arrival" part to your passport, and you should fill this in for when you re-enter Japan.

See [here](http://www.immi-moj.go.jp/english/tetuduki/zairyuu/specialre-entrypermit.html) for more information, and any conditions, etc.

Note that there are other images floating around for "special re-entry permit", but this is the only card I've ever actually seen at the airport.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.immi-moj.go.jp/english/tetuduki/kanri/shyorui/06.html, if you are applying personally only the following documents are required:

- Application form
- Passport and residence card (or alien registration certificate deemed equivalent to a residence card)